# Launch my two apps in split screen with one launcher - Android

Tags: android, multi-window, split-screen

In Android, I have developed two Apps. I want to launch both apps in split screen mode programmatically with one launcher. How do I do that?

Comment: It's possible for sure i can make app Pair's in my `Samsung s8+` but i think it's more dependent on whether the device support's it or not . Samsung does.

Comment: @Anmol so how do we do it, do u know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

You can use Accessibility API for such feature. It doesn't require any permissions.

`android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService` has following apis:

`service.performGlobalAction(GLOBAL_ACTION_TOGGLE_SPLIT_SCREEN)` which you can use to initiate split screen mode.

public List getWindows () to check wether split screen mode is on. Look for a window with AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_SPLIT_SCREEN_DIVIDER

You also will need to play with intent flags when launching activities.

```
 val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeBasic().toBundle()?.apply {
     putInt(
         ActivityOptionsFlags.KEY_LAUNCH_WINDOWING_MODE,
         ActivityOptionsFlags.WINDOWING_MODE_SPLIT_SCREEN_PRIMARY
     )
     putInt(
         ActivityOptionsFlags.KEY_SPLIT_SCREEN_CREATE_MODE,
         ActivityOptionsFlags.SPLIT_SCREEN_CREATE_MODE_TOP_OR_LEFT
     )
 }

 startActivities(listOf(intentBottom, intentTop).toTypedArray(), options)
```

Using this accessibility apis and intent flags you can achieve your goal. Consult [this](https://github.com/stavangr/SplitScreenLauncher) repo by stavangr for detailed implementation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Comment: But this is not working for android 13 :/ ANDROID guys~!!

Answer (score 0):

I did search about this long time back but never found any content to launch multiple application using single launcher.Best case i got is in my Samsung device(after s8 series) which support's application pairing(manual by user [doc](https://www.samsung.com/au/support/mobile-devices/about-app-pair/))

What i believe is that `Samsung` are allowing it as they must have supported it for there custom Android OS.Just like they have there own custom context Menu code and many other tweaks.

[Reference gif](https://im2.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2-3dfdea182209.gif)